# R: how does a foreach loop find a function that should be invoked?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, mpi

I have problems when I use a foreach loop (using `%dopar%`) which invokes a self-defined function. There is not really a problem when I work with Linux, but when I use Windows the self-defined function cannot be found. It is hard to explain the problem in words, so I composed a small example to show it. Assume I have a collection of three simple functions, where `FUN2` (using `%do%`) and `FUN3` (using `%dopar%`) invoke the first one (`FUN`):

```
FUN <- function(x,y,z) { x + y + z }
FUN2 <- function(a, b) {
  foreach(i=1:3) %do% FUN(i, a, b)
}
FUN3 <- function(a, b) {
  foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% FUN(i, a, b)
}
```

The functions are stored in a script called `foreach_testfunctions.R`. In another script (`foreach.test`) I source these functions, use `library(doParallel)` and try to use the functions. First I do it with Linux and all works fine:

```
source("foreach_testfunctions.R")
a <- 2
b <- 3
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel()

foreach(i=1:3) %do% FUN(i, a, b)    ## works fine
FUN2(a, b)                          ## works fine
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% FUN(i, a, b) ## works fine
FUN3(a, b)                          ## works fine
```

Then I do it in Windows:

```
source("foreach_testfunctions.R")
a <- 2
b <- 3
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(3)
registerDoParallel(cl)

foreach(i=1:3) %do% FUN(i, a, b)    ## works fine
FUN2(a, b)                          ## works fine
foreach(i=1:3) %dopar% FUN(i, a, b) ## works fine
FUN3(a, b)                          ## does not work
Error in FUN(i, a, b) : task 1 failed - "Could not find function "FUN""
```

Conclusion: (1) No problems with `%do%`. (2) Problems with `%dopar%` when using Windows. I tried inserting the line `clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("FUN", "a", "b"), env=environment())` before the line that invokes `FUN3` to make sure that the function `FUN` and the variables a and b are found in the proper environment, but the error remains.

My questions: Why does Windows behave different than Linux although the code is identical (apart from the different `registerDoParallel` syntax)? How can I make sure that Windows **does** find function `FUN` when invoked via function `FUN3`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They behave differently because `registerDoParallel` registers an `mclapply` backend on Linux, while it registers a `clusterApplyLB` backend on Windows.  When using an `mclapply` backend, there are essentially no data exporting issues, so it works on Linux.  But with `clusterApplyLB`, you can run into problems if `foreach` doesn't auto-export the functions and data that are needed.

You can solve this problem by modifying `FUN3` to export `FUN` via the `.export` option:

```
FUN3 <- function(a, b) {
  foreach(i=1:3, .export='FUN') %dopar% FUN(i, a, b)
}
```

This solution works on both Linux and Windows, since `.export` is ignored by the `mclapply` backend.

As pointed out by Hong Ooi, you have an error in your use of `clusterExport`, but I wouldn't use `clusterExport` to solve the problem since it is backend specific.

Comment: +1 nice answer. What if `FUN` has not been previously sourced? (i.e., is not present in the working environment)? Is it possible to make it available inside `foreach` by exporting the corresponding R file? (e.g., .export=`"path/to/FUN.R"`). In other words, does `.export` work for files in addition to R objects?

Comment: @Steve Weston the reason is that in my case each worker needs to write to a `.txt` file, call an executable taking the file as input, and read back the output of the `.exe` (which is another `.txt` file). I was wondering whether `.export` could make available (copy) the `.exe` file to each worker' temporary working directory

Comment: @Antoine No, you can only specify the name of one or more variables with the foreach `.export` argument. Beyond that, I usually use backend-specific methods of initializing workers, such as `clusterExport` or `clusterEvalQ` when using doParallel, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In your `clusterExport` call, remove the `env=environment()` part. What you're doing is telling `clusterExport` to look for your objects in a brand new environment, so naturally it doesn't find them.